# Does anyone know where I can find the reference Ozeki.Media.MediaHandlers.Video.CV;?

Tags: c#, sdk, camera, ocr

I'm trying to create a license plate detection system using C# and I'm using camera SDK. There's a reference there that says Ozeki.Media.MediaHandlers.Video.CV; but there's no such thing on the zip file that I downloaded that leads straight or even close to that reference. Can someone explain to me how or where can I get this reference?

Comment: Could you please indicate the source of SDK?

Comment: This is the link of the project: https://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3043/how-to-implement-automated-license-plate-recognition-in-csharp-using-o

The source of the SDK is from Ozeki Camera SDK

Comment: It [does not seem](http://www.camera-sdk.com/doc/html/7593e9e0-822f-201c-5abd-a0eed25c54ed.htm) that the `Ozeki.Media.MediaHandlers.Video` namespaces defines the `CV`

Comment: Can you help me understand what it means? I'm new to this, sorry. :(

Comment: It seems like that their generated documentation is out-dated. Based on [this tutorial](https://camera-sdk.com/p_6776-how-to-creat-an-edge-detecting-application.html) it should be part of the SDK.